# Use one animation object for multi views

Tags: android

I want set alpha animation to views but with one object without create many object like this `fadeIn1 , fadeIn2 , fadeIn3 etc`

```
View1 , View2 , View3
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setStartOffset(1000);
fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
view1.startAnimation(fadeIn); //I want show this after 1 second
fadeIn.setStartOffset(1500);
view2.startAnimation(fadeIn); //I want show this after 1.5 second
fadeIn.setStartOffset(2000);
view3.startAnimation(fadeIn); //I want show this after 2 second
```

But all views shows after 2 second together , Why ?

Comment: Because you're using one animation object, it overrides the other timer, Use animator set for that, it will play sequentially.

Comment: @MohanSaiManthri Can you leave example please , I'll appreciate it.

Comment: example was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AnimatiorSet for this

**Note**: The below code was in kotlin.

First create an function which returns an animator by taking view

```
 private fun getAnimation(view: View): Animator {
    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 0f, 1f).apply {
        duration = 1000
    }
}
```

Then after user AnimatorSet.playSequentially to play one after other.

```
 AnimatorSet().apply {
        playSequentially(listOf(getAnimation(btn_1),getAnimation(btn_2),getAnimation(btn_3)))
        interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
        start()
    }
```

Please free to ask any query in comment section, I'll try to answer as soon as possible :)

Comment: @user12033682  I've tested before adding here, It worked perfectly.

Comment: here is the link for video
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P6DNLyAp5GY8SN1B5SsfIxoOzsB7USF_/view

Answer (score 0):

You need AnimationSet ex:

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```